# Prevent panning outside of map bounds in d3v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

in d3 v3, I used [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/shawnbot/6518285) to prevent panning outside of an SVG. Here's the relevant code:

```
.on("zoom", function() {
    // the "zoom" event populates d3.event with an object that has
    // a "translate" property (a 2-element Array in the form [x, y])
    // and a numeric "scale" property
    var e = d3.event,

    // now, constrain the x and y components of the translation by the
    // dimensions of the viewport
    tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0], width - width * e.scale)),
    ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1], height - height * e.scale));

    // then, update the zoom behavior's internal translation, so that
    // it knows how to properly manipulate it on the next movement
    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

    // and finally, update the <g> element's transform attribute with the
    // correct translation and scale (in reverse order)
    g.attr("transform", ["translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")","scale(" + e.scale + ")"].join(" "));
}
```

In d3 v5, it doesn't work anymore. All the examples allow the map to pan ridiculous amounts off screen. My goal is that the rightmost edge of the map never goes further left than the rightmost edge of the div, etc. How can I accomplish this? Are there any more recent examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you linked, these are the necessary changes inside the `zoom` function for that to work with D3 v5:

```
var e = d3.event.transform,
tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.x, width - width * e.k)),
ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.y, height - height * e.k));
```

Besides that, change the group translate function and remove `zoom.translate([tx, ty]);`.

Here is the original code with those changes:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Restricted zoom behavior in d3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // first, define your viewport dimensions
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;

    // then, create your svg element and a <g> container
    // for all of the transformed content
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("background-color", randomColor),
      g = svg.append("g");

    // then, create the zoom behvavior
    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      // only scale up, e.g. between 1x and 50x
      .scaleExtent([1, 50])
      .on("zoom", function() {
        // the "zoom" event populates d3.event with an object that has
        // a "translate" property (a 2-element Array in the form [x, y])
        // and a numeric "scale" property
        var e = d3.event.transform,
          // now, constrain the x and y components of the translation by the
          // dimensions of the viewport
          tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.x, width - width * e.k)),
          ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.y, height - height * e.k));
        // then, update the zoom behavior's internal translation, so that
        // it knows how to properly manipulate it on the next movement
        // and finally, update the <g> element's transform attribute with the
        // correct translation and scale (in reverse order)
        g.attr("transform", [
          "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")",
          "scale(" + e.k + ")"
        ].join(" "));
      });

    // then, call the zoom behavior on the svg element, which will add
    // all of the necessary mouse and touch event handlers.
    // remember that if you call this on the <g> element, the even handlers
    // will only trigger when the mouse or touch cursor intersects with the
    // <g> elements' children!
    svg.call(zoom);

    // then, let's add some circles
    var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(d3.range(300).map(function(i) {
        return {
          x: Math.random() * width,
          y: Math.random() * height,
          r: .01 + Math.random() * 50,
          color: randomColor()
        };
      }).sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.r, b.r);
      }))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      });

    function randomColor() {
      return "hsl(" + ~~(60 + Math.random() * 180) + ",80%,60%)";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It does indeed stop the drawing from panning off the side, thanks. Is there a way to "recenter" the zoom? When I run this snipper, it tends not to zoom under the cursor, but more like where the cursor would be. For example, if you try to drag the circles to the right from the left edge, then zoom near the center, the svg actually zooms around the left edge still.

Comment: That's strange, it zooms right under the cursor for me.